# "Answer deleted" message floats above "question should be closed" dialog

Tags: bug, design, flag-dialog

I wanted to close a question, but at that moment a answer got removed. This caused the "answer was deleted" box to be shown above the "close dialog".

This is a bug, because the "close dialog" should be shown above because that is a dialog where users should interact, while the "answer was deleted" should be shown below the dialog because that only applies to the answer.

[image]

A fix for this would applying the following CSS:

```
#popup-close-question {
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: Wow.  What a corner case.  But yeah that looks messed up.

Comment: However, a "question was deleted" message should probably still be float above the close-vote dialogue. So likely needs more than only that CSS.

Comment: @bergi with questions, this problem is actually less because they try to close all open dialogs when they are deleted. Of course, there are still race conditions you can use to get this bug

Comment: Today got the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IOdv.png). So still an active bug