# Bug with deleted notification header?

Tags: bug

Recently while posting an answer to a question, OP has deleted his deleted it. As a result, the real time deleted notification message displayed.

[image]

After sometime, the notification header shows up.

[image]

At that point of time, I just scrolled the page down to the bottom. While doing so I noticed that the real time notification message element(the pink one) overlaps the notification header(the orange one).

[image]

And I believe that the notification header should over lap the real time notification message. like below,

[image]

Since it is acting as a page header. What do you guys think about it? Is it a bug or this have to be ignored?

Comment: Same problem as [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317632/answer-deleted-message-floats-above-question-should-be-closed-dialog): the "This post has been deleted" banner floats over everything.