# not able to flag sometimes if any below post delete

Tags: discussion, design

I was trying to give flag on answer,but at same time below the another answer gave by some user got deleted and the view of flag popup covered by that message. and I was not able to give flag and type. I think this must be issue with some design.

[image]

Comment: That's actually pretty funny. Not sure what sort of discussion you're looking for, though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279261/this-post-has-been-deleted-boxs-z-index-is-too-high-overlaps-dialog-overlays

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317632/answer-deleted-message-floats-above-question-should-be-closed-dialog